# How do I pass values from my array variable into a function call inside a for loop using loop counter

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I pass the values of my array into a function within a for loop, going through all the array's values.

I've tried searching but can't find my answer.

Here and an example:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayVariable.length; i++){
    doSomeStuff(arrayVariable[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is that not working?  Note that your "i" variable should almost certainly be explicitly declared locally with `var`, but other than that your code is fine.

Comment: What you have looks good. What's the problem?

Comment: I'll recheck my code execution, I thought this was my problem with something formatted wrong.

Comment: What "problem" are you seeing?

Comment: So apparently it was working, and now I don't know what the problem really was.